# Getting data pushed to an array outside of a Promise

Tags: node.js, youtube, promise, bluebird

I'm using https://github.com/Haidy777/node-youtubeAPI-simplifier to grab some information from a playlist of Bounty Killers. The way, this library is setup seems to use Promise via Bluebird (https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) which I don't know much about. Looking up the Beginner's Guide for BlueBird gives http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/beginners-guide.html which literally just shows

> This article is partially or completely unfinished. You are welcome to create pull requests to help completing this article.

I am able to set up the library

```
var ytapi = require('node-youtubeapi-simplifier');
ytapi.setup('My Server Key');
```

As well as list some information about Bounty Killers

```
ytdata = [];

ytapi.playlistFunctions.getVideosForPlaylist('PLCCB0BFBF2BB4AB1D')
     .then(function (data) {
         for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
             ytapi.videoFunctions.getDetailsForVideoIds([data[i].videoId])
                  .then(function (video) {
                      console.log(video);
                      // ytdata.push(video); <- Push a Bounty Killer Video
             });
          }
});

// console.log(ytdata); This gives []
```

Basically the above pulls the full playlist (normally there will be some pagination here depending on the length) then it takes the data from `getVideosForPlaylist` iterates the list and calls `getDetailsForVideoIds` for each YouTube video. All good here.

The issues arises with getting data out of this. I would like to push the video object to `ytdata` array and I'm unsure whether the empty array at the end is due to scoping or some out of sync such that `console.log(ytdata)` gets called before the API calls are finished.

How will I be able to get each Bounty Killer video into the `ytdata` array to be available globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> console.log(ytdata) gets called before the API calls are finished

Spot on, that's exactly what's happening here, the API calls are async. Once you're using async functions, you must go the async way if you want to deal with the returned data. Your code could be written like this:

```
var ytapi = require('node-youtubeapi-simplifier');
ytapi.setup('My Server Key');

// this function return a promise you can "wait"
function getVideos() {
    return ytapi.playlistFunctions
        .getVideosForPlaylist('PLCCB0BFBF2BB4AB1D')
        .then(function (videos) {
            // extract all videoIds
            var videoIds = videos.map(video => video.videoId);

            // getDetailsForVideoIds is called with an array of videoIds
            // and return a promise, one API call is enough
            return ytapi.videoFunctions.getDetailsForVideoIds(videoIds);
        });
}

getVideos().then(function (ydata) {
    // this is the only place ydata is full of data
    console.log(ydata);
});
```

I made use of ES6's arrow function in `videos.map(video => video.videoId);`, that should work if your nodejs is v4+.

Comment: Worth mentioning to our friend this is EcmaScript 6 code :)

Comment: Yeah I'm 5+ I'm going to try this out now because it was close to the idea I had in mind I just didn't know how the heck Promise worked

Comment: Also I need two API calls because Youtube only returns the duration of a video in specific API calls. Edit I see what you are saying now >.<

Answer (score 1):

console.log(ytdata) should be immediately AFTER your FOR loop. This data is NOT available until the promise is resolved and the FOR loop execution is complete and attempting to access it beforehand will give you an empty array.

(your current console.log is not working because that code is being executed immediately before the promise is resolved). Only code inside the THEN block is executed AFTER the promise is resolved.

If you NEED the data available NOW or ASAP and the requests for the videos is taking a long time then can you request 1 video at a time or on demand or on a separate thread (using a webworker maybe)? Can you implement caching?

Can you make the requests up front behind the scenes before the user even visits this page? (not sure this is a good idea but it is an idea)

Can you use video thumbnails (like youtube does) so that when the thumbnail is clicked then you start streaming and playing the video?

Some ideas ... Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, so are you saying there is no way to wait on this data so I can get it after all the data is complete? 

It doesn't take super long but isn't that short either. Also in line with that you are saying I can decrease the request to 1 video but this is on the assumption that the request will finish before `console.log(ytdata)`?

Ideally, the idea was to pull this data before a user even hits the page, I guess the other way to accomplish this will be to just populate a database with the data thus skipping youtube quota entirely. Though then it becomes manual if the playlist changes

Comment: I'll rewrite your code in a separate answer explaining it - one sec :)

Comment: In respect of storing data (e.g. caching it) then you could, every 10 minutes, make a new request to YTAPI to check that nothing has changed. I expect the YTAP request for getVideosForPlaylist is much quicker than the request for getDetailsForVideoIds - and only the first request is needed to check for changes

Comment: Yeah saw your code in the next answer. The reason for the two API calls is because Youtube API doesn't provide duration per video in the playlist API call only in the video list API call so I need the two calls. I wouldn't be loading any actual youtube video with this until later in the app. Thanks for the different ideas with this. I'm voting on this and not your other answer since that answer might get flagged as a code only answer and they basically both say the same thing yeah?

Answer (score 1):

```
ytdata = [];

ytapi.playlistFunctions.getVideosForPlaylist('PLCCB0BFBF2BB4AB1D')
     .then(function (data) {
         // THE CODE INSIDE THIS THEN BLOCK IS EXECUTED WHEN ALL THE VIDEO IDS HAVE BEEN RETRIEVED AND ARE AVAILABLE
         // YOU COULD SAVE THESE TO A DATASTORE IF YOU WANT

         for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
             var videoIds = [data[i].videoId];
            ytapi.videoFunctions.getDetailsForVideoIds(videoIds)
                  .then(function (video) {
                      // THE CODE INSIDE THIS THEN BLOCK IS EXECUTED WHEN ALL THE DETAILS HAVE BEEN DOWNLOADED FOR ALL videoIds provided
                      // AGAIN YOU CAN DO WHATEVER YOU WANT WITH THESE DETAILS
                      // ALSO NOW THAT THE DATA IS AVAILABLE YOU MIGHT WANT TO HIDE THE LOADING ICON AND RENDER THE PAGE! AGAIN JUST AN IDEA, A DATA STORE WOULD PROVIDE FASTER ACCESS BUT YOU WOULD NEED TO UPDATE THE CACHE EVERY SO OFTEN
                      // ytdata.push(video); <- Push a Bounty Killer Video
             });
             // THE DETAILS FOR ANOTHER VIDEO BECOMES AVAILABLE AFTER EACH ITERATION OF THE FOR LOOP
          }
          // ALL THE DATA IS AVAILABLE WHEN THE FOR LOOP HAS COMPLETED
});

// This is executed immediately before YTAPI has responded.
// console.log(ytdata); This gives []
```

Comment: WARNING: I have just noticed ... ytdata.push(video); ... could be an array of videos since you are passing multiple videoIds to getDetailsForVideoIds(videoIds) .. i would expect the response in this scenario to be an array not a single video ... be careful you don't accidentially end up with arrays within arrays :) just an FYI

Comment: Oh ok noted. I'll be sure to check on that.